# Static arrays VS. dynamic arrays in C++11

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++11, move-semantics

I know that it's a very old debate that has already been discussed many times all over the world. But I'm currently having troubles deciding which method I should use rather than another between static and dynamic arrays in a particular case. Actually, I woudn't have used C++11, I would have used static arrays. But I'm now confused since there could be equivalent benefits with both.

First solution:

```
template<size_t N>
class Foo
{
    private:
        int array[N];

    public:
        // Some functions
}
```

Second solution:

```
template<size_t N>
class Foo
{
    private:
        int* array;

    public:
        // Some functions
}
```

I can't happen to chose since the two have their own advantages:

- Static arrays are faster, and we don't care about memory managment at all.
- Dynamic arrays do not weigth anything as long as memory is not allocated. After that, they are less handy to use than static arrays. But since C++11, we can have great benefits from move semantics, which we can not use with static arrays.

I don't think there is one good solution, but I would like to get some advice or just to know what you think of all that.

Comment: Your two solutions should be: your first one, or a vector and no size_t template. You should avoid using raw pointers where an STL container can be used without any problem.

Comment: @fontanini: If you were to modify for C++11, then the two solutions should be `std::array<T,N>` or `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas yes sir!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will actually disagree with the "it depends".  Never use option 2.  If you want to use a translationtime constant, always use option 1 or std::array.  The one advantage you listed, that dynamic arrays weigh nothing until allocated, is actually a horrible, huge disadvantage, and one that needs to be pointed out with great emphasis.

**Do not ever have objects that have more than one phase of construction**.  Never, ever.  That should be a rule committed to memory through some large tattoo.  Just never do it.

When you have zombies objects that are not quite alive yet, though not quite dead either, the complexity in managing their lifetime grows exponentially.  You have to check in every method whether it is fully alive, or only pretending to be alive.  Exception safety requires special cases in your destructor.  Instead of one simple construction and automatic destruction, you've now added requirements that must be checked at N different places (# methods + dtor).  And the compiler doesn't care if you check.  And other engineers won't have this requirement broadcast, so they may adjust your code in unsafe ways, using variables without checking.  And now all these methods have multiple behaviors depending on the state of the object, so every user of the object needs to know what to expect.  **Zombies will ruin your** (coding) **life.**

Instead, if you have two different natural lifetimes in your program, use two different objects.  But that means you have two different states in your program, so you should have a state machine, with one state having just one object and another state with both, separated by an asynchronous event.  If there is no asynchronous event between the two points, if they all fit in one function scope, then the separation is artifical and you should be doing single phase construction.

The only case where a translation time size should translate to a dynamic allocation is when the size is too large for the stack.  This then gets to memory optimisation, and it should always be evaluated using memory and profiling tools to see what's best.  Option 2 will never be best (it uses a naked pointer - so again we lose RAII and any automatic cleanup and management, adding invariants and making the code more complex and easily breakable by others).  Vector (as suggested by bitmask) would be the appropriate first thought, though you may not like the heap allocation costs in time.  Other options might be static space in your application's image.  But again, these should only be considered once you've determined that you have a memory constraint and what to do from there should be determined by actual measurable needs.

Comment: Yeah, your commment makes sense. When reading my code again, I realized that I was actually never having zombie objects since memory was allocated at construction though. So don't worry about that.
Right, the only advantages were the gain from move operations in the end (already provided by std::vector if used). The only drawback of using a vector there would be some overhead compared to std::array. But I don't know if std::array has move semantics...

Comment: On the stack, you don't typically need moves, you need Return Value Optimisation, which although compiler-specific, is fairly universal.  Other cases where moves might be used can almost always be done in-place (no copy), or when a copy is needed, it's actually needed (to put memory of one type into a different place), so moves don't work.

Answer (score 4):

Use neither. You're better off using `std::vector` in nearly any case. In the other cases, that heavily depends on the reason why `std::vector` would be insufficient and hence cannot be answered generally!

Comment: I already know of this rule of thumb. I would be for professionnal work, I would use it. However, I like to experiment and earn experience from trying. Moreover, I did not really need anything else than random access in the present case. That's why I considered trying my hand at this.
And, yeah, as std::vector depends on implementation, there can be a big overhead if I use many instances of this class since the size of the array is not really meant to be changed after.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm currently having a problem to decide which one I should use more than another in a particular case.

You'll need to consider your options case-by-case to determine the optimal solution for the given context -- that is, a generalization cannot be made. If one container were ideal for every scenario, the other would be obsolete.

As mentioned already, consider using `std` implementations before writing your own.

More details:

**Fixed Length**

- Be careful of how much of the stack you consume.
- May consume more memory, if you treat it as a dynamically sized container.
- Fast copies.

**Variable Length**

- Reallocation and resizing can be costly.
- May consume more memory than needed.
- Fast moves.

---

The better choice also requires you understand the complexity of creation, copy, assign, etc. of the element types.

And if you do use `std` implementations, remember that implementations may vary.

Finally, you can create a container for these types which abstract the implementation details and dynamically select an appropriate data member based on the size and context -- abstracting the detail behind a general interface. This is also useful at times to disable features, or to make some operations (e.g. costly copies) more obvious.

In short, you need to know a lot about the types and usage, and measure several aspects of your program to determine the optimal container type for a specific scenario.

Comment: In the present case, since I needed template specializations for N<4, I thought that I could use static arrays for those and dynamic ones when N is bigger. The memory being allocated once and the array never resized, it's not a big overhead.
Since I like your ideas in the last part of your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @ex0du5 examples: member swap and move are fast with vectors. array requires no allocation/lock, growth/lock, or out of place resizing.

Comment: @ex0du5 it's part of copying cost